# How to structure AWS CDK for product development

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

Our company is exploring the use of AWS CDK.  Our app is composed of an Angular Front End and an ASP.NET Core 3.1 Back End.  Our Angular Front End is deployed as a static site in an S3 bucket.  Back End is deployed as a Lambda with an API Gateway to allow for public API calls.  The database is an Aurora RDS instance.

The app is a core product that will have some client-specific config when deployed into a client-specific AWS environment.  Code-wise we are looking to keep the core product the same.

Based on the reading I did, placing CDK code alongside app code would allow us to define Constructs that correspond to app components (e.g. Front End S3 Buckets, Back End Lambda + API Gateway, RDS setup, etc.), all located in the same repo.  I was thinking of producing artifacts (e.g. Nugets, binaries, zips) from the core app and cdk builds.

Now a client-specific setup would consume artifacts created from the main repository build to create a client-specific build, composed of core app + base AWS CDK constructs.  I can imagine building AWS CDK stacks that use the ones created in the core repo adding client-specific configurations.  Still unsure how to do the core app + client-specific config but am wondering if anyone either solved this problem or has suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can start with  [AWS CDK Best Practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/best-practices.html) with special attention to *Coding best practices* section. Second, you can refer to AWS Solution Architect article who describes [Recommended AWS CDK project structure for Python applications](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/recommended-aws-cdk-project-structure-for-python-applications/). By default, I understand that python is not Nextjs, though you can see find the general principles in it. Third, you can use [a better way to structure AWS CDK projects around Nested Stacks](https://www.sentiatechblog.com/aws-cdk-structure-components) and start to convert the Stacks into Libraries and re-using the code.